Azure Devops pipeline with optional, manually triggered stage
I am using Azure DevOps YAML pipelines and have two stages - one is deploying to dev (is triggered by commit in master), and the second is checking pull requests (running tests and static analysis). These stages are executed based on variables, e.g. variables['Build.Reason'] or variables['Build.SourceBranchName'].
The pull request checks are set as required in branch policy, so the pipeline must pass before the author can merge it.
What I want is to allow the author to manually trigger deploy to dev from pull request (e.g. because there are changes in infrastructure, environment variables, etc.) to make sure everything works before the changes are merged upstream.
Example 1: I am changing just one function. I want the pipeline to run the static analysis and tests successfully and then merge the PR.
Example 2: I am integrating a new external service (e.g. emailing) and I want to make sure everything works. So the pipeline will trigger static analysis and tests and finish successfully (and would allow me to merge if I wanted to). However, because it is a bigger change with external integrations, at this point I want to trigger deploy to dev and check if everything works. This is still done from PR, not from the master, because I want to fix issues if they occur before the change is upstream.
In both cases (Example1 as well as Example2), after mege to master changes will be deployed to dev.
What I tried so far

Using ManualValidation@0 task: not applicable, because then the pipeline is not successful. As the pipeline is required to pass before the merge request, the author can't merge it without the deployment to dev.
I didn't try deployment jobs, but I suspect these work similarly.
Use parameter, like DeployDevFromPR, that should indicate whether the pipeline should check to code, or deploy it. Then set two branch policies, one automatic and required (the checks) and one manual and optional (the deployment). However, there is no possibility to set the env variable from the PR view (unless the author requeue the pipeline again), so the manual step runs the check.
Decide based on variable variables['Build.QueuedBy']: the value is different when pipeline is triggered automatically. For user, there is its username, but for automatic triggers there is "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS". However, this breaks if the user wants to rerun the check pipeline (then the QueuedBy will be the user).

Can I somehow get to the desired effect to allow user deploy from PR manually without blocking the merge?
Thank you

This statement is a bit confusing: "allow the author to manually trigger deploy to dev from pull request" - if the build will run as part of the pull request validation it will be triggered automatically.
Maybe configuring an environment with approvals and using it in a deployment job might help?

Can you share a sample YAML pipeline to understand your current workflow and requirement? Do you expect the first stage to be changed to deploy to dev upon PR creation not PR merge?

As far as I understand, currently the first stage of the pipeline was triggered by PR merge
commit as a CI trigger; and your PR validation build triggered the second stage of the same pipeline?

@RuiJarimba I provided two examples that describe the cases I want to cover. Hopefully it is more clear now?


I am using Azure DevOps YAML pipelines and have two stages - one is deploying to dev (is triggered by commit in master), and the second is checking pull requests (running tests and static analysis)

Instead of using a single pipeline with 2 stages consider splitting the pipeline in two:

Test pipeline: runs the tests and static analysis
Deploy pipeline: deploys the code

After splitting the pipelines, create a build policy in the Build Validation section for each one:

Test pipeline policy should be set as required, i.e. the build must always run as part of the pull request validation
Deploy pipeline policy should be set as optional - it is up to the PR creator to decide if this build should be run as part of the pull request validation or not

Example of a policy for the Deploy pipeline:


Thank you, this seems to solve the problem. It's a little pity that it requires multiple files and manual intervention to create the pipeline in GUI :( I kind of expected I could specify "pipelines:" key and specify all of them in a single file.
Nevertheless, It works as I wanted to so thank you.

Based on your requirement of a single pipeline solution, you may consider evaluating a variable from a Variable Group to prevent running the stage3 to deploy Dev during a PR validation, since such variable values are outside the pipeline definition and are processed at pipeline runtime.
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: stage1
  condition: and(
                eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'),
                eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')
              ) 
  jobs:
  - job: DeployToDevUponCI
    steps:
    - pwsh: |
        Write-Host "This is stage 1 deploying to Dev upon CI trigger"

- stage: stage2
  dependsOn: []
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
  jobs:
  - job: Tests
    steps:
    - pwsh: |
        Write-Host "This is stage 2 running tests upon PR validation trigger"
        Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]stage2succeeded" # Add Build tag to filter the latest artifacts for download during stage3
    - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
      artifact: drop$(Build.BuildId)

- stage: stage3
  dependsOn: stage2
  variables:
  - group: VG-DeployDevUponPR
  condition: eq(variables['DeployDevUponPR'], 'True')
  jobs:
  - job: DeployToDevUponPR
    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        buildType: 'specific'
        project: 'TheProjectName'
        definition: 'DeployDevUponPR'
        buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
        tags: 'stage2succeeded'
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    - pwsh: |
        Write-Host "This is stage 3 deploying to Dev upon CI trigger"
        tree $(Pipeline.Workspace)
        Write-Host "DeployDevUponPR - $(DeployDevUponPR)"
        Write-Host "After deployment - Reset the variable DeployDevUponPR in variable group 36 as false"
        az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id 36 `
          --name DeployDevUponPR `
          --org $(System.CollectionUri) `
          --project $(System.TeamProject) `
          --value False
      env: 
        AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
      displayName: Reset the variable DeployDevUponPR in variable group 36 as false
      condition: always()

   


When the pipeline was triggered by a PR, the stage3 was always skipped, until you manually set the variable value in the variable group as True. The PR validation build status was also succeeded. And when you would like to deploy the stage3, you could create a new run with only stage3 selected, which would not be displayed on the PR page. You may also use Azure DevOps CLI script to update all required environment variables into the variable group during stage2 for stage3 to consume.

By the way, the Build.Reason for the new build to deploy stage3 is Manual not PullRequest. If temporarily storing the environment variables in a variable group is an option for you, it should work in separate pipelines as well.
